# Viewing clothbake during cloth bake

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am performing a clothbake. The cloth baking is successful, however during the cloth bake, the current result is not being shown in the 3d-view window as the bake is being performed. So the 3d-view window always shows the cloth as it was at the start of the bake.
At the end of the bake I can see the final results by viewing the individual frames.

Is there a way or setting to view the cloth bake in action during the bake?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that this is sort of flaky.  If the bake cache is empty, the current frame is 1, and I click the "play" button, it *usually* does what you're asking for: it bakes and shows the current state in the 3D View window.  Emptying the cache doesn't always work, though.  One way to quickly clear it is to click the "Pinning" checkbox off and on (or on and off, depending on how you have it set).

**[Edit]** I saw another post on here that said that playback has to be set to "No Sync" (which I think is the default).

Comment: I've been clicking the "Bake" button instead of the "Play" button. I tried it again but clicked the "play" button now, and the 3d view shows the action in realtime. However, still when clicking the "bake" button, the issue above still happens. So I guess I just need to click the play button from now on to start the bake, instead of hitting the bake button.

Comment: That's what I do.  I'm not even sure what purpose the "Bake" button serves, unless it's more efficient (e.g., if you're going to be baking overnight).

Comment: I'm just wondering if it is just an issue of my computer not being fast enough to perform the bake and update the 3d view at the same time. It is intermittent: sometimes the 3d view updates, sometimes it doesn't, like you mentioned. Maybe Blender could improve it a bit to allow more time/priority for the 3d-view to render.

Comment: I doubt it's a matter of computer power.  My models aren't that complex, and it still sometimes takes a number of seconds per frame.  The flakiness I mentioned was possibly user error, since lately I never see it bake without playing (I do often have it play without baking, usually because I forget to start over at frame 1).